# Work with dates on bash

Tags: bash, shell, date, time

I'm trying to work on dates on a shell script :
I want to get data that require a command containing a date on this form :

```
2010.06.18_00:00:00_TAI
```

In my script, I would like to do a loop to write commands every 45 seconds during one day. So I need to get strings like these :

```
2010.06.18_00:00:45_TAI

2010.06.18_00:01:30_TAI

2010.06.18_00:02:15_TAI
```

...

How can I do that automatically please ?

Thank you !

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best way to do it. What a about a `cron job` and a script using `watch`?

Comment: `I'm trying to work on dates on a shell script` -- tell us what you tried thus far.

Comment: `sleep 45` might help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print data in specific format, `date` command can do that:

```
$ date "+%Y.%m.%d_%H:%M:%S_TAI"
2013.07.16_14:01:51_TAI
```

Answer (score 0):

Requires GNU `date`

```
time=$(date -d 2010-06-18 +%s)    # midnight June 18
datetime=$(date -d @$time +%Y.%m.%d_%T_TAI)
day=${datetime:8:2}
while [[ ${datetime:8:2} = $day ]]; do
    echo $datetime
    ((time+=45))
    datetime=$(date -d @$time +%Y.%m.%d_%T_TAI)
done
```

Here's a different but similar implementation that seems a lot faster

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    t=mktime("2010 06 18 00 00 00")
    d=strftime("%d", t)
    while (d==strftime("%d", t)) {
        print strftime("%Y.%m.%d_%T_TAI", t)
        t+=45
    }
}'
```